# Randomly closing app - InputManagerService: Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification

Tags: android, remoteexception

I've a very simple **Android** app, similar to fingerpaint application. I'm
drawing some lines on the screen with my finger.

My problem is that, app closes itself randomly, taking me back to
Android home screen.

Only log I can see on LogCat is that line:

```
(Warning) Tag: InputManagerService: Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 4962 uid 10077.
```

No exception is thrown.

I've tried compiling project against Android 2.0, 2.1 and 2.2...

I've tried disabling debuggable attribute in manifest.

I'm having this problem on both Nexus One and 2.2 Emulator.

Comment: Make sure your LogCat level is set to Verbose and you actually see all output. I am sure there is some output there that you missed.

Comment: I have this problem when working with AudioRecorder. It also happens randomly. Have to restart the phone.

Comment: @Pentium10, I'm pretty sure that's not true.  I'm seeing something similar.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was drawing on Canvas object from 2 different threads.

I was playing around Android's FingerPaint.java SDK sample and it's accessing Canvas within onTouchEvent. However I was also using SurfaceView and drawing on Canvas within my animation thread.

Therefore removing Canvas object access from onTouchEvent(main app thread) **solved my problem**.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks.
thats definitely not my problem.  I'm noticing it happen more often when the progress dialog closes.