# WinDeath on notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite

Hi I have following problem:

```
data.clear();
data.addAll(datasource.getFilesInFolder());  //gets the data from Sqlite database
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

generates this logCat output :

```
 12-19 14:34:30.864: W/Binder(986): Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
 12-19 14:34:30.864: W/Binder(986): java.lang.NullPointerException
 12-19 14:34:30.864: W/Binder(986):     at        android.inputmethodservice.IInputMethodWrapper.setSessionEnabled(IInputMethodWrapper.java:280)
 12-19 14:34:30.864: W/Binder(986):     at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethod$Stub.onTransact(IInputMethod.java:129)
 12-19 14:34:30.864: W/Binder(986):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
 12-19 14:34:30.864: W/Binder(986):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
 12-19 14:34:30.864: W/InputMethodManagerService(757): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 30040 uid 10174
```

This exception causes WIN DEATH...

Well I realized maybe it is the other way round, WIN DEATH causing this log output, because in log WINDEATH comes before this, then I have no idea why does windeath occur.

My adapter is extended BaseAdapter with nothing really special in it. Very strange is the following :

The mentioned piece of code is inside a custom listener which is triggered from another class. When I put the problematic part outside the listener it works well.

I does the `Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation` mean ? Can it be a problem with a database ? or maybe my custom listener ?
Anyone has an idea what's wrong ?

Comment: Are you sure this stack trace is associated with this bit of code?

Comment: Pretty sure, when i comment notifyDataSetChanged, the problem is gone...but the list is not updated

Comment: That's bizarre. What sort of `Adapter` is this?

Comment: edited the question, tried to explain more. thaks for patience.

Comment: can you post your listener code as well. Where it is causing problem

Comment: Are you calling this code from some other thread?

Comment: Can you provide source code of Adapter?

Comment: I switched from Listener to LocalBroadcastReceiver and it solved the problem. Still don't know what caused it not to work with listener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen various problems that have this issue when doing concurrent actions. See for instance [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/kwxPxV_cEkc) (fling + service) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201843/randomly-closing-app-inputmanagerservice-got-remoteexception-sending-setactiv) (drawing on canvas from 2 threads).

You are talking about a custom listener in a different class, could it be that you are also doing several things at once?

Comment: I'm using volley to manage requests, and it queues them, so that's not the cause. the problem is related to how fast I switch between pages.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the data into adapter directly.

Instead of doing

```
data.clear();
data.addAll(datasource.getFilesInFolder());  //gets the data from Sqlite database
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

You should do

```
if(adapter!=null)
{
    adapter.clear();
    adapter.addAll(datasource.getFilesInFolder());  //gets the data from Sqlite database
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I think the adapter is null which is causing the problem in your case