# Xamarin App crashing crashing.

Tags: android, xamarin, crash, xamarin.forms, crash-reports

I'm trying to figure out why my app sometimes crashes. Xamarin Forms application. Running on emulator running Android 4.4.

It crashes sometimes. I'm not sure if the final stack trace is a cause or symptom of the crash:

> 09-23 17:38:21.418: W/Binder(1144): Caught a RuntimeException from the
>   binder stub implementation. 09-23 17:38:21.418: W/Binder(1144):
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 09-23 17:38:21.418: W/Binder(1144):    at
>   android.inputmethodservice.IInputMethodWrapper.setSessionEnabled(IInputMethodWrapper.java:280)
>   09-23 17:38:21.418: W/Binder(1144):   at
>   com.android.internal.view.IInputMethod$Stub.onTransact(IInputMethod.java:129)
>   09-23 17:38:21.418: W/Binder(1144):   at
>   android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404) 09-23 17:38:21.418:
>   W/Binder(1144):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method) 09-23
>   17:38:21.418: W/InputMethodManagerService(648): Got RemoteException
>   sending setActive(false) notification to pid 1763 uid 10052

Full log here: https://gist.github.com/pcresswell/2a1cfc0cb250f398085f591aef77cca2

Any suggestions on where to hunt down next are appreciated.

Comment: You have something going out of scope, thus the null pointer. `android.inputmethodservice.IInputMethodWrapper.setSessionEnabled` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20683255/windeath-on-notifydatasetchanged

Comment: Looking at it now, the ActivityMonitor process is terminating the app I believe: 09-23 17:38:21.310: I/ActivityManager(648): Force stopping com.chexus.mondelez appid=10052 user=0: from pid 3292
09-23 17:38:21.310: I/ActivityManager(648): Killing 1763:com.chexus.mondelez/u0a52 (adj 0): stop com.chexus.mondelez