# Function in SQLite connection class causing Runtime Exception

Tags: android, sqlite

I have `DataBase Table` in which i have COULMNS `KEY_ID(INT)`, `EMAIL(TEXT)`, `PASSWORD(TEXT)`, `FIRST_NAME(TEXT)`, `LAST_NAME(TEXT)`

I have a function in **SqliteConnection Class** :

```
public String Well(String el,String pl)
{
    SQLiteDatabase pox =this.getReadableDatabase();
    String qr="SELECT "+FIRST_NAME+" FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+EMAIL+" = "+el+" AND "+PASSWORD+" = "+pl;
    Cursor cur =pox.rawQuery(qr,null);
    String itemname =  cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(FIRST_NAME));
    pox.close();
    cur.close();
    return  itemname;

}
```

In the above function i am passing `EMAIL as e1` and `PASSWORD as p1` and trying to fetch `FIRST_NAME` of user that matches `EMAIL and PASSWORD.`
When i call this function inside any other activity than its causing a `java.lang.NullPointerException` exception. Is there any problem in this function.

**LogCat**

```
12-02 11:02:36.943 2368-2368/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/graphics/drawable/Icon;)
12-02 11:02:36.943 2368-2368/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.ImageView.setImageIcon, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageIcon
12-02 11:02:36.943 2368-2368/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16525: Landroid/widget/ImageView;.setImageIcon (Landroid/graphics/drawable/Icon;)V
12-02 11:02:36.943 2368-2368/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
12-02 11:02:37.073 1559-1574/system_process W/ActivityManager: Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
12-02 11:02:38.343 1670-1681/com.android.inputmethod.latin W/Binder: Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
                                                                     java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                         at android.inputmethodservice.IInputMethodWrapper.setSessionEnabled(IInputMethodWrapper.java:280)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethod$Stub.onTransact(IInputMethod.java:129)
                                                                         at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
12-02 11:02:38.343 1559-1713/system_process W/InputMethodManagerService: Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 2323 uid 10055
12-02 11:02:38.353 2368-2368/com.example.sony.sqloperations I/Choreographer: Skipped 83 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-02 11:02:40.533 1559-1573/system_process I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.example.sony.sqloperations/.MainActivity: +4s448ms (total +13s453ms)
12-02 11:03:00.013 1616-1616/com.android.systemui D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb8f0e180: ver 2 0
12-02 11:03:00.093 1616-1616/com.android.systemui D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 20284K, 67% free 10469K/30824K, paused 50ms, total 68ms
```

Comment: share your  crash log with question

Comment: @Prem Logcat added

Comment: share your code for **android.widget.ImageView.setImageIcon**

Comment: It works perfectly if i dont call the above mentioned function, is this function causing exceptions for other class.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20683255/windeath-on-notifydatasetchanged

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya do you think the function is correct? , please tell me

Comment: Not that I can see how it is causing the issue you are explaining. The method **`Well`** has a flaw in that it is not moving the cursor to point to a row. The cursor when initially retrieved is positioned to before the first row. To position, you could use `if(cur.moveToFirst()) { String itemname =  cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(FIRST_NAME));}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, Use **`SINGLE`**  quote in **SELECT** Statement .

```
  "SELECT  _FIRST_NAME FROM " + TABLE_NAME +" WHERE FIELD_NAME='"_FIELD_VALUE "' AND FIELD_NAME_TWO='" _FIELD_VALUE_TWO  "'";
```

Then

```
 if (cursor.moveToFirst()) 
 {
     String itemname = cur.getString(0); // Or (cur.getColumnIndex(YOUR_FIELD_NAME));     
 }
```

Comment: i solved it the reason was the query was not correctly formatted although i accepted your answer as its the same as i solved it